# Having issue with Firefox 8 for Mac: window.name is undefined

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've been trying to configure the new Facebook Javascript API with my website, but I'm facing an issue with Firefox (working perfectly fine with Chrome and Safari, yet to test out on IE fully but have been informed of no issues).

The issue is being pointed out in the beginning of Facebook's all.js file, with the message saying

```
window.name is undefined
if(!window.FB)window.FB={_apiKey:null,...return document.getElementById(a);}}; 
all.js (line 3)
```

Hence, any subsequent accesses to the SDK using FB. results in an error stating

```
FB is not defined
[Break On This Error] FB.login(function(response)
```

The code that I've used is

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
    appId      : 'my_app_id', // App ID
    channelURL : 'my_channel_file', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    startLoad();
```

};

```
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));
</script>
```

Any clues as to what the issue has? And has anyone faced this error before?

Comment: where is `FB.login` being called?

Comment: it's called from within the startLoad() function mentioned above. Again, I'd like to mention it's working perfectly in chrome and safari, but not on FF

Comment: Issue resolved (see answer below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved: unbelievably, the only minor error was that I was using a global variable inside my JS file called "name". That's a serious no-no with the Facebook SDK (though not mentioned anywhere). I found the reasoning on a link I can't remember, but the primary issue is that the global name variable is mangled up with the window.name which is required by the FB api.

I'd simply suggest avoiding a global variable called name whether or not you use the Facebook SDK. Just in case.

Comment: had the same issue, renamed the global `var name`, now it works. thx for the hint!

Comment: Glad I could help you out. The issue is barely documented, took me forever to find out about it.

Comment: Great! I had this exact problem as well. Strangely it only affected Firefox--things worked fine on Chrome. Poor form on Facebook to depend on such poorly named globals!

Comment: Is there a way to prevent third party libs to overwrite that variable. Does facebook prevent that?

Comment: @chchrist: not that I know off and seems very unlikely Facebook would. It would typically be up to the developer behind the third party library to ensure it can work in conjunction with Facebook's SDK.