# Cross domain using window.name -- double onload should be used?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I'm struggling with myself to figure out why my code works in a specific way ( rather than the other way)  :

```
+----------------------------+
| jsfiddle                   |
|                            |
|              +---------+   |
|              |         |   |
|              |  jsbin  |   |
|              +---------+   |    
+----------------------------+
```

Goal :

`jsfiddle`  should connect to `jsbin` and `jsbin` should **return** data to `jsfiddle` using `window.name` ( cross domain technique).

*(Again --the code is working)*

`jsbin's` response is a Html page with :

```
  <script>
      window.name = 1*(new Date());
  </script>
```

And here is the code for `jsFiddle`:

```
/*1*/   var f;
/*2*/   
/*3*/   function loadRequest()
/*4*/   {
/*5*/       f.onload = function ()
/*6*/       {
/*7*/           alert(f.contentWindow.name);
/*8*/           frame.parentNode.removeChild(frame);
/*9*/       }
/*10*/       f.src = 'about:blank';
/*11*/   }
/*12*/   
/*13*/   $(".b").on('click', function ()
/*14*/   {
/*15*/       f = document.createElement('iframe');
/*16*/       f.name = framename = 'fetchData';
/*17*/       f.onload = loadRequest;
/*18*/       f.src = 'http://jsbin.com/AjUyoYU/8/quiet';
/*19*/       document.body.appendChild(f);
/*20*/   });
```

As you can see  - the code works  : **http://jsfiddle.net/7Nawt/2/**

So where is the **question** ?

Looking at line #17 , I **do** attach an `onload` handler for the `iframe`. (`loadRequest`).

But the `loadRequest` method - in turn --attaches **again(!! --line #5)** an `onload` function.

I dont understand why it *is* working like this .

I mean : the common sense tells me that the `loadRequest` method should be :

```
function loadRequest()
    { 
             alert(f.contentWindow.name);
             frame.parentNode.removeChild(frame);
    }
```

But it is not working.

What am I missing ? *( any other attempts display   : a cross domain error)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send the iframe window back to a domain that is accessible to the parent window before you check `window.name`, otherwise you'll get the cross-domain error. So, after it loads and the remote page sets `window.name`, you send it to `about:blank`, which isn't subject to the same-origin policy, and then read `window.name` from the parent window.

The **first** trick here is that `window.name` sticks around no matter where you send the window. So, you send the window to a remote domain, let it set `window.name`, send it back to an accessible domain, and then read it.

The **second** trick is that `about:blank` is a happy environment for Both `A` and `B`. and so - no cross domain errors.

Comment: another solution is that the window inside the iframe will change its location after setting name - but then i'll have to wait twice for page load at the page. ( in order to read the name)

Comment: That could work. I think it's safe to do it from the outer page, though. The onload shouldn't fire until the script runs and the rest of the page loads. Also, about your second trick edit, it's more about being a happy environment for A; B shouldn't matter. You could send it back to domain A instead of about:blank if you wanted.